# Multiple cron:run 2>&1

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

I have a site with magento 2.4 in AWS with kubernetes and I try to execute the jobs with bin/magento cron:install. This generate in crontab a new line:
[image: crontab -l]

The problem is when I check with command top the processes I see multiple cron:run executing:
[image: Command top]

processes overlap and causes the machine to reboot

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior when cron running, might be to upgrade your server with more RAM and CPU.